How to access object initialized by ConfigurationProvider
I have created a custom ConfigurationProvider in order to configure and start up a container from the testcontainers-dotnet package.
I have run into an issue, where I need an HttpClient initialized by the provider available when I set up dependency injection for my tests, but I'm unsure how I can make it accessible.
The process has to happen in this order, steps 2 or 3 could happen outside of the provider if I am able somehow to make either the container or httpClient created in it available to my WebApplicationFactory.

Provider configures and starts up TestContainer
HttpClient is created from the started container
HttpClient is injected as a dependency

As an example of my provider approach working well, this is a stripped down version of the basic configuration for the WireMock module.
I'm able start the container and then send the mappings to the WireMock client that will be used in the tests. I can also utilise the Set() function, inherited from ConfigurationProvider, to override values that would normally come from my appsettings file.
public class WireMockConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
    public IList<MappingModel> Mappings { get; }

    public WireMockConfigurationSource(IList<MappingModel> mappings)
    {
        Mappings = mappings;
    }

    public IConfigurationProvider Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder) => new WireMockConfigurationProvider(this);
}

The bulk of the work happens in the ConfigurationProvider (IDisposable code ommited)
public class WireMockConfigurationProvider : ConfigurationProvider
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory TaskFactory = new(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);

    private readonly WireMockContainer _container;
    private readonly WireMockConfigurationSource _source;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cts;

    public WireMockConfigurationProvider(WireMockConfigurationSource source)
    {
        _source = source;
        _container = new WireMockContainerBuilder()
            .WithAutoRemove(true)
            .WithCleanUp(true)
            .Build();
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        if (_cts is not null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        TaskFactory.StartNew(() => LoadAsync(_cts.Token), _cts.Token).Unwrap().ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public async Task LoadAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // My container is started
        await _container.StartAsync(ct);

        // The URL for the container provided to my settings
        SetAppSettingsForWireMockedComponent();

        // Some data is set up on the container for tests
        await InitializeMappings(ct);
    }

    private async Task InitializeMappings(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var wireMockAdminClient = _container.CreateWireMockAdminClient();
        await wireMockAdminClient.PostMappingsAsync(_source.Mappings, ct);
    }

    private void SetAppSettingsForWireMockedComponent()
    {
        var containerUrl = _container.GetPublicUrl().TrimEnd('/');

        Set("MyAppSetting:ApiUrl", containerUrl);
    }
}

This is then used by ConfigureAppConfiguration from my WebApplicationFactory
public class ApiFactory<TProgram> : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    where TProgram : class
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configure => configure.Add(new WireMockConfigurationSource()));

        builder.ConfigureServices(
            (context, services) =>
            {
                // DI for test run
                // This is where I would have to inject my HttpClient
            });
    }
}

The would like to reuse the same approach for the CosmosDB module. However, I need to be able to access the WireMockContainer that's started up in the provider outside of the ConfigurationProvider. This is because the container creates a HttpClient with a trusted certificate, so you can send authorized requests to the CosmosDB instance,
    var cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(
        // connection string for the emulator, this can be passed to app settings via "Set()" so no issues accessing the value outside of the Provider.
        _container.GetConnectionString(),
        new CosmosClientOptions
        {
            // The HTTP client created from the container automatically trusts the emulators certificate. 
            // Without this HttpClient, you get 401 denied when sending requests to CosmosDB.
            // It will be needed outside of the provider to create a CosmosClient for dependency injection
            HttpClientFactory = () => _container.HttpClient,
            ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
        });


I assume this question relates to the GH comment #1068. In general, this is something I really want to improve somehow. I think it could simplify the process of providing dependent services a lot. I haven't had the time to look closer into your setup (that's why I haven't commented yet on GH). Right now, I think you cannot use the TC provided HTTP client, but I guess you can simply set the connection string as a setting and then create your own configured HTTP client with the connection string?

The connection string is the AccountEndpoint and AccountKey, so it can be used for connecting to cosmos (which works) but it can't be used to create the HttpClient that trusts the CosmosDbEmulators certificate.

If I 'Set()' the docker hostname to my configuration settings. I could potentially create my own DelegatingHandler, like the UriRewriter class. I would then have an appsetting that was only used in a test project, which feels like a hack and not great for consumers of a library.

"If I 'Set()' the docker hostname to my configuration settings.":
Use the host and port from the connection string to set up the delegation handler, and simply register the handler in ConfigureTestServices. This is not very different from configuring an SQL client using a connection string configuration for instance. While this may not be a perfect solution (due to the necessary delegation handler), it will work fine. Please note, this is not a limitation of Testcontainers, but rather of how ASP.NET works. Or at least, I don't know of a better solution (for now) — sorry.

If you come up with something better, let me know. I am curious. We can also continue to discuss the issue until we find a suitable solution on GH.
